# One-to-Many Many-to-One mapping , server tries to find a nonexisting table

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have two entities `Student` and `Group`. There is a 3rd entity named `StudentGroup` which contains a reference to `Student`, a reference to `Group` and a `Date` field.

I try to implement a **one-to-many** relationship between `Student` & `StudentGroup` , **many-to-one** vise versa. Same idea applies to `Group` & `StudentGroup`.

`Student` **class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private int sid;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<StudentGroup> studentGroups;

 //Setter & Getter

}
```

`Group` **class:** is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private int gid;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<StudentGroup> studentGroups;

 //Setter & Getter

}
```

`StudentGroup` **class:** :

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "student_groups")
 public class StudentGroup {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "lastChanged")
        private Timestamp lastChanged;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="sid")
        private Student student;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="gid")
        private Group group;
        //Setter & Getter
    }
```

Mapping definition:

```
<mapping class="com.my.db.Student" />
<mapping class="com.my.db.Group" />
<mapping class="com.my.db.StudentGroup" />
```

When I start my tomcat server, I always get following **error**:

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: student_student_groups
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1302)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
```

Why server tries to find `student_student_groups` table which I haven't defined in any place ?

Comment: Are all your annotations from the `javax.persistence` package?

Comment: @David , Yes, they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in JPA if you didn't annotate your relations with `@JoinColumn` a Join Table created for joining between relations, in your case a Join table between `student` and `student_groups` should be exist, if you add `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property set to `create` a join table created as well, but if you want to avoid using join table you can use `@JoinColumn`annotation in your relation:
for example:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN_NAME")
```

Comment: That's not what I observed in my hibernate usage. A `mappedBy` attribute as used by the OP should generate a default `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: But I have "@JoinColumn" in "@ManyToOne" annotation in StudentGroup class, please check my update

Comment: With JoinTable I could fix my problem (jpa-xml):
`<many-to-one name="project" fetch="EAGER" >
<join-table name="project_empl"><inverse-join-column/></join-table>
</many-to-one>`